# pandas: Buffer has wrong number of dimensions (expected 1, got 0) when transforming a dataframe column of sets

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with a column containing one-element sets. The one-elements are always of type `str`. I want to change this column's values to that one `str` inside each set.

My understanding of pandas so far has lead me to use the `transform` function on my dataframe. Because I only want to change one column, I call it on that column specifically.

I've tried `map`, `transform`, and `apply` (I can't(?) use applymap because the column is simply a series). Examples of what I've tried is this:

```
df['foo'].map(''.join)
df['foo'].transform(''.join)
df['foo'].apply(''.join)
```

this returns my column as a series, but doesn't change `df`'s `foo` column's values in-place. I then tried these:

```
df['foo'] = df['foo'].map(''.join)
df['foo'] = df['foo'].transform(''.join)
df['foo'] = df['foo'].apply(''.join)
```

swap out `''.join` for `lambda x: next(iter(x))` and the same error occurs.

some sample data from `head(df)` (thanks for the suggestion Yuca):

```
treatment             AAA        AAA        AAA  ...       BBB        BBB   foo                               
15025                 0.0        0.0        0.0  ...  126250.0   191730.0  {K00134}
6746            1523000.0  2374300.0  1394500.0  ...  536750.0  1179000.0  {K00134}
11097           1146200.0   423280.0   316280.0  ...       0.0   115880.0  {K00895}
3098             193000.0    57943.0    94483.0  ...       0.0   191530.0  {K01689}
14797             53168.0        0.0    65262.0  ...       0.0        0.0  {K00169}
```

`[5 rows x 9 columns]`

I think my understanding of `apply`, `map`, `transform`, etc. needs some work, but I just want to figure out how to do this and maybe why my method doesn't work. Thanks!

Comment: it's always encouraged to provide sample data, it makes it easier for us to provide accurate answers

Comment: I don't really get the problem, which error occurs ? Using apply, it should work fine.

Comment: @jsgounot I get a "`ValueError: Buffer has wrong number of dimensions (expected 1, got 0)`" error when I try any of the lines with `=` in it. The lines without `=` return the properly-transformed column as a series, but `df['foo']` remains the same.

Comment: I can't replicate your problem I am afraid. All of the above work for me (I reduced your sample df even more thou.

Comment: side note: your columns have repeated names, it's a good idea to avoid that

Comment: @Yuca good point but still doesn't explain why he gets that error

Comment: @Yuca yes, I'm going to try changing the column names to keep them distinct. The columns originally came from a 3-level MultiIndex that had 2 out of 3 levels dropped. Maybe this is part of the problem, I've noticed other answers on SO referencing this `ValueError` being because of duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

**fix**: as @Yuca mentioned, I had duplicate column names. This was because I had earlier removed 2/3 levels from the original MultiIndex assigned to `df`'s columns. When I re-assigned the columns with unique names, the lines with `=` worked! Thanks everyone for your help.